# Running Multiple websites with same profiles

Tags: seo, social-networking

Is it a bad practice in terms of search traffic to maintain multiple websites in the same niche. For example using the same set of social profiles from twitter, facebook and g+ and using them on two websites related to laptop shopping.

I am interested to know the search traffic impact with and without using social sharing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not is a bad practice for SEO at all. You could be penalize for duplicate content but the socials profiles would not do that.
Every day is more important the impact in social networks just to take more reputation and more traffic at all. Your profile of Google+ just will do, that your profile will improve as author.
Soon will be important the reputation from authors and without a good SEO position of your website if you are good position as author the sites where you will collaborate will have better reputation.
I expect it will help to you.

Comment: It is not good practice to have multiple website on same niche (you should not go for doorway pages) that is bad practice in search engine point of view.